# How to send desktop notifications to clients using flask

Tags: python, flask, notifications, backend

This is code for winotify package:

```
from winotify import Notification,audio
    
toast=Notification(app_id="text classification",
                                title="Notification",
                                msg="File Downloaded",
                                duration="short"
                                )
                
toast.set_audio(audio.Default,loop=False)
toast.show()
```

When I implement this in the flask I'm getting notification, instead of users who are using the web page. Is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: To be clear, your expectation was that this code would be executed on your Flask clients’ local machines? How did you reach that conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Plyer](https://pypi.org/project/plyer/) to do it, something like this:

```py
def yourMethod():
    # Something
    notification.notify(
        title='Title Here',
        message='Message Here',
        app_name='Your App Name'  # Customize as needed
    )
    # Return if you want
```

Comment: but using plyer we don't get like a desktop notification  right , it is like we get some popup and it disappears quickly , people might not even notice

Comment: So, you wanna do something like Whatsapp Web?

Comment: but by using winotify we get the desktop notifications just as like mail notification but as I mentioned in the question I'm getting the notification instead of users ,I'm new to flask ,don't have that much idea about it

Comment: It's not like whatsapp web , it is for text classification for some use case , So they use the webpage to get the classified results as excel file  , here the model which I've used  takes some time , So I thought if they get a notification when the file download is completed, it will be easy for them

Comment: 1)Why not use a `js alert`? Its simple, and i think that is the best option for a "results donwload completed" message. 2) Please add more of your code to facilitate the analisis.